# How to execute a function on every pixel move using jQuery's scroll() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I've got a situation where I need to execute a simple function when the user scrolls the page. The problem is that jQuery's `scroll` method only fires intermittently (by design obviously), but I need a way of having it fire on every pixel move...

I have put together a js fiddle demonstrating what I mean...

http://jsfiddle.net/nGtSV/1/

What I'm trying to do is have the `console.log` in my fiddle fire 100 times if the user scrolls down/up 100 pixels (once for each pixel). Is this possible?

Comment: The scroll event doesn't fire intermittently, it fires each time the box scrolls. Clicking the scroll arrow fires the scroll event and dragging the scroll bar fires the scroll event the same number of times.

Comment: Yeah, my wording is probably not ideal. I was hoping that there was a way to have the scroll event fire for every pixel though

Comment: It is not possible and using a setInterval to watch the scroll position can not capture every pixel of movement.

Comment: Cheers epascarello, I'll update my answer with a sample of what I'm trying to achieve... there may well be an easier way

Comment: Scrollbars aren't guaranteed to scroll a single pixel at a time (and often don't due to obvious physical limitations), so you'll likely never get a consistent result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, it is not possible that jquery fire the event in each "pixel move".
But you can iterate your operation for each pixel by saving previous position:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fn3nt/

Comment: Benoit, that's a clever workaround... I don't think that will work in my situation - I'll update my answer later on tonight with some more information

Answer (score 1):

Use:

http://jsfiddle.net/nGtSV/5/